# Retrieving href link for HTML element via String returning function?

Tags: javascript, html, url, reactjs

I am using React.js and I am attempting to retrieve an address link for the following html element in my render function:

```
<a class="form-label" href={this.link.bind(this)}> Link </a>
```

The function link is as follows:

```
link() { 
return "192.168.3.9:8080/cars/" + this.state.carType; 
}
```

Where `this.state.carType` stores the type of car stored as a string.

However this is the link that I am directed to:

*localhost:8080/function%20()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D*

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you're suppose to use an onClick event

Comment: Can't you just put that url in the href? ``href={"192.168.3.9:8080/cars/" + this.state.carType}``

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is add ReactRedirect and use accordingly

follow the link [ReactRedirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redirect)

```
link() { 
return (
   <ReactRedirect location={`192.168.3.9:8080/cars/${this.state.carType}`}>
  </ReactRedirect>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the link function in the constructor, like this example, it works.

```
constructor() {
   super();

   this.state = {
     carModel: "325i"
   };

   this.getLinkUrl = this.getLinkUrl.bind(this);
}
getLinkUrl() {
  return "http://192.168.3.9:8080/cars/" + this.state.carModel;
}
```

[Test link](http://codepen.io/Tiendq/pen/KNPNJX)